# What is a spatial complexity of a non recursively written Fibonacci algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pascal, fibonacci

What is a spatial complexity of a **non recursively** written Fibonacci algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you write it. It can use constant space for the two previous numbers and the counter, plus linear space for the whole result, *if* you want to save it.

(as pointed in a comment below, this holds if you assume that each memory location can store integers of arbitrary size. This is a common assumption, but better be aware of it)

Comment: So it can be Linear  or Constant  spatial complexity?

Comment: @AleksandreKhachaturov Yes, depending on whether you store all the numbers or not

Comment: So If I will store all numbers, then it will be Linear, 
otherwise Constant right ?

Comment: @AleksandreKhachaturov yup.

Comment: This assumes that memory locations can store arbitrarily sized integers, since just the nth Fibonacci number needs around n lg(phi) bits. That's not wrong, but it's an assumption.